# x86 code - Call through ds segment selector?

Tags: assembly, x86, windbg

I am debugging something at the level of 32-bit x86 code on windows using windbg.  Something has confused me and and I have whittled it down to a *call* that appears to go through the ds segment selector, which apparently I don't understand.

This below is just the minimal example to reproduce my confusion, it is not the actual issue I am dealing with.

I have a function in a DLL

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl MyDllTest_Cdecl(int i);

void __cdecl MyDllTest_Cdecl(int i)
{
    printf("In MyDll MyDllTest_Cdecl(%d)\n", i);
}
```

In an executable, I link to the DLL statically and call the function

```
void __cdecl MyDllTest_Cdecl(int i);

MyDllTest_Cdecl(1);
```

Debugging the process in windbg, execution is at the site of the function call where I find the following machine code as shown by windbg

```
call    dword ptr [UseDll_Static!_imp__MyDllTest_Cdecl (00062118)] ds:002b:00062118={MyDll!MyDllTest_Cdecl (68391100)}
```

I have source mode in windbg off, (*l-t*) so the trace command (*t*) should always just single-step through the machine code and not hide anything.

When I use the trace (*t*) command, execution suddenly moves to 0x68391100 (as the disassembly of the call command showed).

How does this work?  Where does the address 0x68391100 come from?  An x86 disassembler shows that the machine code ff1518219e00 is

```
call   DWORD PTR ds:0x00062118
```

just as windbg shows.

I understand that the compiler/linker/loader uses indirection through *call* and *jmp* instructions, especially for calls to a function in a DLL.  I see that in other cases but I am able to single-step through each *call* and *jmp* that comprise the C-level function call.  In this case, it is a single step.  So this is not an indirection of *call* and *jmp* instructions created by the compiler/linker/loader.

At address 0x00062118 I see the following:

```
0:000> u 00062118
UseDll_Static!_imp__MyDllTest_Cdecl:
00062118 0011            add     byte ptr [ecx],dl
0006211a 396820          cmp     dword ptr [eax+20h],ebp
0006211d 1139            adc     dword ptr [ecx],edi
```

So there is no *jmp* or *call* there that might be part of an indirection.  It is the address of the symbol *UseDll_Static!_imp__MyDllTest_Cdecl* but the code there looks like garbage.

The symbols can be ignored, I would just like to know how

```
call   DWORD PTR ds:00062118
```

moves execution to 0x68391100. The *ds* register is 0x002b.

I think I basically understand x86 segmentation in real mode.  But I thought on modern Windows in protected mode the virtual memory was basically a flat 2^32 address space.  Anyway if there was some segmentation offset, in this case it would be  *0x68391100* - *0x00062118* which is *0x6832efe8*.  I would expect offsets to end in one or more zeros.

This may be completely irrelevant but when I try display the *0x002b* selector (which is what is in the *ds* register) with the *dg* command in windbg it shows

```
0:000> dg 0x002b
                                  P Si Gr Pr Lo
Sel    Base     Limit     Type    l ze an es ng Flags
---- -------- -------- ---------- - -- -- -- -- --------
002B 00000000 ffffffff Data RW Ac 3 Bg Pg P  Nl 00000cf3
```

Thanks for any help...it is a simple question but I am trying to avoid focusing on how functions in DLLs are linked and loaded, or focusing on the history of x86 real mode segmentation.  I just want to understand at the level of the machine code.

Comment: The code is in flat model. The address of the function being called is stored in  ds:00062118, so you'll need to look at that location to get the address, then look at that address to see the code.

Comment: you do not disassemble the target location you dump the dword instead of u 00062118 do dd 00062118 L1 you will get 68391100

Comment: That's an indirect jump/call, note that `dword ptr []` as the operand, not a bare symbol for a direct relative jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x00062118 is the segment offset where the actual function address is stored.
If you look at your disassembly, the first four bytes at 0x00062118 are 0x00, 0x11, 0x39, and 0x68. They would be loaded into EIP in reverse order, yielding 0x68391100, which is the address you jumped to!

Comment: That's it, thanks!  I knew it was something simple.  I was misled by the fact that in other cases (Debug build) calls to a DLL function the indirection is achieved through multiple call or jmp instructions, rather than through a single call instruction that is indirected at the level of machine code.